# How to backup Kubuntu 15.04 config/settings?

Tags: 15.04, kubuntu, backup, settings, plasma

I would like to backup all my settings for the plasma desktop, dolphin, kate etc. I am working with kubuntu 15.04. How can I do this?

Reason is: just a few moments ago my plasmashell crashed (black screen, also after reboot) and I had to reset ~/.kde ~/.chache ~/.config/plasma* in order to fix it. So I lost some of my settings, I want to prevent this from happening again by saving all the settings somewhere for me to recover. Also handy after een clean install where I delete my /home folder.

I already looked up a few tools:

-Kup backup: http://kde-apps.org/content/show.php?action=content&content=147465

-plasmabac: https://linuxtidbits.wordpress.com/2009/11/04/plasmabac-when-plasma-solidifys/

But I am not sure if this will work, as I am very new to Linux.